# Javascript is not working in webView when Loaded from asset folder but working from both http server & localhost

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, webview

I am trying to load `offline version of python documentation` into an `webview` from `asset`folder. The offline docs work perfectly in my pc web browser in offline but not working properly in `webview` (something like `jquery is missing`).

```
@SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.wrapper);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
        webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/python/index.html");
    }

}
```

And this error message is shown when I tried to load the home page or navigate to any page.

```
09-24 01:03:02.789: E/Web Console(479): ReferenceError: Can't find variable: $ at file:///android_asset/python/index.html:164
```

And the above error is for a Jquery code snippet ( I think this for that the jquery library isn't loading)

```
<script type="text/javascript">$('#searchbox').show(0);</script>
```

But when I load those pages from my local server `localhost` or `http` server, this is working perfectly. What did I miss?

**Edit**
Showing nothing in the `webView`. After using `loadDataWithBaseURL`:

```
@SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.wrapper);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
        AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();
        String htmlPage = null;
        InputStream input;
        try {
            input = assetManager.open("python/index.html");

            int size = input.available();
            byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
            input.read(buffer);
            input.close();
            // byte buffer into a string
            htmlPage = new String(buffer);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
            webView.loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///android_asset/", htmlPage, "text/html", "utf-8", "");

    }
}
```

Comment: try adding one more back slash in the url    file:////android_asset/python/index.html

Comment: the url is perfectly working and page loads successfully but not rendering properly

Comment: Sorry, I thought it was the issue with loading

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was - I extracted those web files from a phonegap app's asset folder; those had some additional files ad different structure. That's why it was not working in Android naive environment !

Answer (score 1):

Your html page should be having reference to

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.4.min.js">
</script>
```

Since you say the docs should load offline the jquery js is not being loaded. You could probably bundle jquery along with your application and reference it locally like this

```
  <script src="file:///android_asset/js/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
```

Also include

```
<script src="file:///android_asset/js/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
```

You might also have to load your html page using loadDataWithBaseURL as seen below instead of loadUrl.

```
 AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();
            String htmlPage=null;
            InputStream input;
            try {
                input = assetManager.open("python/index.html");

                int size = input.available();
                byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
                input.read(buffer);
                input.close();
                // byte buffer into a string
                htmlPage = new String(buffer);

            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }   
webView.loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///android_asset/", htmlPage, "text/html", "utf-8", "");
```

**Note:** jquery-1.8.2.min.js and jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.js files should be present in your assets folder.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I am going to give it a try. what is `htmlPage` is above code snippet?

Comment: htmlPage is the actual html page that has to be loaded. loadDataWithBaseURL requires that the html page be provided as a string. I have modified my code to include that. Hope that helps.

Comment: I changed my code according your suggestion but this time it is showing nothing in the webview! I have edited my question. please take a look.

Comment: Has the reference to jquery been updated in the html? Also include <script src="file:///android_asset/js/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.js"></script>

Comment: this are my external script inclusion code `<script type="text/javascript" src="_static/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="_static/underscore.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="_static/doctools.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="_static/sidebar.js"></script>` should I change all to absolute path?

Comment: Okay just to check bundle these js files within your application. Under your assets folder create a folder called js place all your js files within this folder and change the reference as seen here <script src="file:///android_asset/js/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="file:///android_asset/js/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="file:///android_asset/js/underscore.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="file:///android_asset/js/doctools.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="file:///android_asset/js/sidebar.js"></script>

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37966/discussion-between-s-a-norton-stanley-and-kaidul-islam-sazal)

Comment: I don't need `jquery mobile`. Please don't misguide. Thanks anyway! :)

Comment: I did mention "just to check", was trying to help. Your welcome.